# StorageItemThumbnail Access Permissions

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

Does anyone know when/where one can write the StorageItemThumbnail?

I.e. it seems not to work in the MusicLibrary although the "Music Library" permission allows to read, change and delete files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For files I don't believe it's possible (unlike a thumbnail for a Contact or something with a read-write backing store). File thumbnails are pulled from the file system thumbnail cache, which Windows maintains automatically using cached images of set sizes.